# An elegant way of finding the closest value in a circular ordered list

Tags: python

Given a **sorted** list such as `[1.1, 2.2, 3.3]` and a bounding value such as `math.pi*2`, return the closest value for any given value from `[0 - math.pi*2)`

The function should return the index of the value, so that `f(1.2)` returns `0` while `f(2.1)` returns `1`, and `f(6.0)` should wrap around at `math.pi*2` and return `0`, being closer to 1.1 than to 3.3 given the bounding value. Just to be entirely explicit, this function should also wrap around on on the lower end, so that `f(1.0, [5.0, 6.0], bound = math.pi*2)` returns `1`.

The use case is to map an arbitrary angle in radians to the nearest existing valid angle in the list. I've written this kind of function a couple of times in python with `bisect`, but the code always ends up offending my aesthetic senses. The high complexity and number of edge cases seems out of proportion with the intuitive simplicity of the function. So I am asking if anyone can come up with a pleasing implementation, both in terms of efficiency and elegance.

Comment: Why don't you just check the wrap-around condition first and then do a binary search?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a more elegant approach. Eliminate the edge cases by wrapping the number line around:

```
from bisect import bisect_right

def circular_search(points, bound, value):
    ##
    ## normalize / sort input points to [0, bound)
    points = sorted(list(set([i % bound for i in points])))
    ##
    ## normalize search value to [0, bound)
    value %= bound
    ##
    ## wrap the circle left and right
    ext_points = [i-bound for i in points] + points + [i+bound for i in points]
    ##
    ## identify the "nearest not less than" point; no
    ## edge cases since points always exist above & below
    index = bisect_right(ext_points, value)
    ##
    ## choose the nearest point; will always be either the
    ## index found by bisection, or the next-lower index
    if abs(ext_points[index]-value) >= abs(ext_points[index-1]-value):
        index -= 1
    ##
    ## map index to [0, npoints)
    index %= len(points)
    ##
    ## done
    return points[index]
```

As written, works unless inputs are wonky like no points, or bound==0.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`bisect` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) as a base:

```
from bisect import bisect_left
import math

def f(value, sorted_list, bound=math.pi * 2):
    value %= bound
    index = bisect_left(sorted_list, value)
    if index == 0 or index == len(sorted_list):
        return min((abs(bound + sorted_list[0] - value), 0), (abs(sorted_list[-1] - value), len(sorted_list) - 1))[1]
    return min((index - 1, index), 
        key=lambda i: abs(sorted_list[i] - value) if i >= 0 else float('inf'))
```

Demo:

```
>>> sorted_list = [1.1, 2.2, 3.3]
>>> f(1.2, sorted_list)
0
>>> f(2.1, sorted_list)
1
>>> f(6.0, sorted_list)
0
>>> f(5.0, sorted_list)
2
```

Comment: `f(0.0, [5.0, 6.0])` incorrectly returns 0, when it should wrap around and return 1. (I thought this behavior was obvious from the original question, but I will add it there to make sure it isn't missed.)

Comment: @porgarmingduod: added better handling of the boundary case.

Comment: so the list elements are not necesarily in the interval 0 - math.pi*2?

Comment: @elyase: The list elements are [0, math.pi*2).

Comment: @porgarmingduod: final adjustment made; boundaries have to be dealt with first, then.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Looks like something went wrong with your formatting.

Comment: @porgarmingduod: oops, c&p left-overs. gone now.

Comment: I'm sure this wasn't working when I started answering, ho hum. Now it is!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be just to use min:

```
def angular_distance(theta_1, theta_2, mod=2*math.pi):
    difference = abs(theta_1 % mod - theta_2 % mod)
    return min(difference, mod - difference)

def nearest_angle(L, theta):
    return min(L, key=lambda theta_1: angular_distance(theta, theta_2))

In [11]: min(L, key=lambda theta: angular_distance(theta, 1))
Out[11]: 1.1
```

Making use of the sorted-ness of the list you can use the [bisect](http://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) module:

```
from bisect import bisect_left

def nearest_angle_b(theta, sorted_list, mod=2*math.pi):
    i1 = bisect_left(sorted_list, theta % mod)
    if i1 == 0:
        i1, i2 = len(sorted_list) - 1, 0
    elif i1 == len(sorted_list):
        i1, i2 = i1 - 1, 0
    else:
        i2 = (i1 + 1) % len(sorted_list)
    return min((angular_distance(theta, L[i], mod), i, L[i])
                 for i in [i1, i2])
```

*Returns the distance, the index and the angle in the list to which it's closest to.*

Comment: watch out for `i1 == 0` too.